# How to unit test LocationListener in Android using Mockito

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener

My LocationManager is set to request location every 5 minutes or 1000 meters. I would like to test that my Network & GPS locationListener are called/notCalled when the distance has changed 1000/999 meters.

Do I have to simulate coordinates?  I have no clue how to do it.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you running it on an Emulator or a real device?

Comment: I want to do unit testing